# Responsive login with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to do a responsive login form with bootstrap 3.
But, when I test it in a mobile device, the page appers small, and have to zoom it.
I want that appears with full width of the phone.
What im doing wrong??

The page: [The page](http://www.smartynet.com.br/societario/users/teste)

The code:

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I found this login page tutorial helpful for my project http://thecomputerstudents.com/web/bootstrap/creating-simple-login-page-template-using-bootstrap/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your HTML HEAD..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```